# Mongoose many to many population with uni-directional references

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, many-to-many, schema

I have the following schemas which are used to represent a many-to-many relationship :

```
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
  title: {type: String},    
});
mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);

var ProductSchema = new Schema({
  title: {type: String},
  categories: [
    {
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Category'
    }
  ]
});
mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema );
```

When I query the Categories or the Products I want to be able to get in the result all the linked documents.

Populating the categories when querying the Product is straightforward:

```
Product.find().populate('categories').exec(...)
```

But how to do this from the Category side? I know I can add an array of ObjectId ref to the Product documents in the CategorySchema. But I'd like to avoid bi-directional referencing (I don't want to maintain it, and have a risk of inconsistency).

**EDIT: here is the solution I implemented**

```
/**
 * List all Categories
 */
exports.all = function (req, res) {
  //Function needed in order to send the http response only once all
  //the categories' product has been retrieved and added to the returned JSON document.
  function sendResponse(categories) {
    res.json(categories);
  }

  AppCategory.list(function (err, categories) {
    if (err) {
      errors.serverError();
    } else {
      _.forEach(categories, function (category, index) {
        category.products = [];
        Product.byCategory(category._id, function (err, products) {
          category.products= category.products.concat(products);
          if (index === categories.length - 1) {
            sendResponse(categories);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
};


ProductSchema.statics = {
  byCategory: function (categoryId, callback) {
    this.find({'categories': categoryId})
      .sort('-title')
      .exec(callback);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to do that. :-) I would guess a product can be in some reasonably-small number of categories, but a category might have many thousands of products. In that case, trying to do `Category.populate('products')` is not going to work from an efficiency standpoint. You'll use lots of memory, not be able to do pagination in a straightforward way, load duplicate product data into memory when a product belongs to several categories, etc. Better to load the products in a category by querying directly against the products collection. You can filter by category easily enough a la `Product.find({'categories._id': $in: arrayOfCategoryIds}})`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I implemented something like you described. I updated my question. Now I can retrieve the Categories with all the Products populated. In my use case I need to retrieve a list of all the products by category and get than in only one JSON document. There will not actually be so many products perhaps only a few hundred max.